# Within a folder search all CSV files for a word and only move the files where the word was found

Tags: string, csv, file, search, move

I have a folder full of csv files.
I need to seperate the csv files from each other based on,
if a specific word that occurs in the file or not.

EDIT: original code was removed, as it was not working anyways.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone wants to solve the same issue:

```
    import os
    import shutil
    import pandas as pd
    
    location = "/home/any_location_you_want/"

    # This is the path where you want to search
    path = location

    # this is the extension you want to detect
    extension = '.csv'

    for file in os.listdir(location):
        filename = os.fsdecode(file)
        file_path = os.path.join(filename)
    
        if filename.endswith(".csv"):
            df = pd.read_csv(file, low_memory=False)
    
#If a .csv file was found we look at the column "sport" to check if the word "cycling" is in it.

#If so, the file will be moved to a cycling-folder

            if (df['sport']).str.contains('cycling').any():
                print("Cycling: ", filename)
                shutil.copy(os.path.join(location, filename), "/home/any_location/cycling")
                os.remove(os.path.join(location, file))

    #if the file has not been moved yet and it contains the word "running", it will be moved to a running-folder and removed from this folder.  

  
            if (df['sport']).str.contains('running').any():
                print("Jogging-File: ", filename)
                shutil.copy(os.path.join(location, filename), "/home/any_location_running")
                os.remove(os.path.join(location, file))
    
    print()
    print("ENDE")
```

Comment: I am open and thankful for any improvement ideas on this code !